# Extjs using formBind: true, not disabling submit button

Tags: javascript, extjs

When I am using formBind: true, it does not seem to (save) and I am not sure why. Any ideas?

```
    title: 'Edit Sessions',
    modal: 'true',
    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'form',
            bodyPadding: 10,
            title: "",
            defaults: {
                labelWidth: 90,
                margin: '0 0 10 0',
                anchor: '90%'
            },
            items: [
                {
                    name: 'title',
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    fieldLabel: 'Title',
                    allowBlank: false,

                },
                {
                    xtype: 'checkboxfield',
                    name: 'approved',
                    fieldLabel: 'Approved',
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            xtype: 'container',
            padding: '10 10 10 10',
            layout: {
                type: 'hbox',
                align: 'middle',
                pack: 'center'
            },
            items:
                [   //Buttons and handlers
                    {
                        xtype: 'button',
                        text: 'Save',
                        formBind: true,
                        type: 'submit',
                        margin: '5 5 5 5',
                        handler: function (button) {
                            var form = button.up().up().down('form');
                            form.updateRecord();
                            button.up('window').destroy();
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        xtype: 'button',
                        text: 'Cancel',
                        margin: '5 5 5 5',
                        handler: function (button) {
                            button.up('window').destroy();
                        }
                    }

                ]
        }
    ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `formBind` only works if the button is in the form.

Working example: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1o4t